# I can't connect my discord bot to my code in repl it with python

Tags: python, bots, chat

I tried making a secret in repl.it to put my bot's token in so i can code my bot but it doesn't recognize the variable TOKEN even though i made a System environment variable. I tried researching to see if someone has the same problem but I couldn't find anyone.

The code I written is in the following:

```
import discord
import os 

client= discord.Client()

@client.event

async def on_read():
  print('We Have Logged In As {0.user'.format(client))

@client.event

async def on_message(message):
  if message.author == client:
    return 

  if message.content.startswith('$hello'):
    await message.channel.send('Hello!')

client.run(os.getenv('TOKEN'))
```

Comment: First one - if you put your token in client.run function, will it work? If yes - problem with adding the token to a System environment, if no - problem with your token.

Comment: I'd start by simply running python and verifying `os.getenv('TOKEN')` actually returns your token. It sounds like it doesn't. Make sure you `export` the token environment variable in your shell before running the Discord client. Alternatively, you could export the token in your shell initialization script, such as `.bashrc`.

Comment: Personally, I prefer Python's dotenv ( https://pypi.org/project/python-dotenv/ ) module as opposed to shell environment variables in this particular case (since the token has no meaningful context outside of this program).

Comment: thanks for the help